# Update GUI controls from a background thread of another class

Tags: c#

I am creating an windows based application which download the data from server.
I am using background thread which is created on different class to perform these download operation.And I want to continuously show the download status on rich textbox i.e on main thread.But i am unable to do this,get an Cross-thread operation not valid.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

method on Form1.cs

```
public void UpdateRichText(string Text)
{
    SetRichText(Text);                     
}

public delegate void SetRichTextTextDelegate(string text);
public void SetRichText(object number)
    {            
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {                
            this.BeginInvoke(new SetRichTextTextDelegate(SetRichText),text);                
            return;
        }

        richTextBox1.Text += number.ToString() + "\n";
    }
     private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        demo d = new demo();
        d.display();
    }
```

methods on demo.cs

```
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    public void display()
    {      
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(call));
        t.Start(); 
    }


    public void call()
    {
    //when i call this method every time if(InvokeRequired) is false.
        f.UpdateRichText("Called from Thread");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your check to:

```
if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired) 
{
    richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(new SetRichTextTextDelegate(SetRichText),text);
```

Comment: AS mentioned in above code i created another class which perform all download operation.

Comment: in that i was created a thread which peform all download operation on background.Now to update the GUI I called a method using form object ex b.display.which internally calls the SetRichText to update richtext.is this right way to call mehods of form..?every time invokerequired is false when i use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following

```
           if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(delegate {  richTextBox1.Text += number.ToString() + "\n";  richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret(); }));

            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += number.ToString() + "\n";
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            }
```

richTextBox1.Text += number.ToString() + "\n"; Can be changed as follows,

**rtbEvents.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + number.ToString() );**